# I can't render in Blender 4.0.2

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I've been trying to render a image to test the render if it works or not, but the result is not and when I cancel it becomes not responding, I waited 30 minutes to respond. I search for solution but still it doesn't work, I use EEVEE not Cycles

[image: here the setting]
[image: render time]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you share your blend file with https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: ah okay, here https://blend-exchange.com/b/7Gz9KdBe